# ObservableCollection.Add() affects a completely different ObservableCollection

Tags: c#

I have a Collection ObservableCollection property and an EditCollection ObservableCollection  property. Its a weird setup with the setters and everything...

```
private ObservableCollection<string> _editCollection;

    public ObservableCollection<string> EditCollection
    {
        get { return _editCollection; }
        set
        {
            _editCollection = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("EditCollection");
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<string> _collection;

    public ObservableCollection<string> Collection
    {
        get 
        {
            return _collection;  
        }
        set 
        { 
            _collection = value;
            _editCollection = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Collection");
            OnPropertyChanged("EditCollection");
        }
    }

public void AddToEditCollection(object item)
    {
        int count = _collection.Count;
        ; // break point: count = 1 as it should
        EditCollection.Add((string)item);
        //EditCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>( new List<string>{ "g", "g", "g" } );
        count = _collection.Count;
        ;// break point: count = 2
    }
```

When I call the Add function on EditCollection, it affects the Collection (or at least its private field). But when I manually call the setter with an equals sign =, it doesnt affect Collection. Anyone know why?

Comment: In the `Collection` setter you set both collections to the same instance, so both Collection and EditCollection refer to the same list instance.

Comment: Oooooooh my baddd